# Calculate font-size with absolute-size

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to calculate with [absolute-size values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#values) (`small`, `medium`, `large`, ...) in SASS or CSS `calc()`.

For example:

```
span {
  font-size: large * 1.5;
}
```

Comment: font-size can be calculated in SASS(SCSS) using for ex. variables  $small, $medium, $large. Also you can use CSS variables - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. [Absolute font size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#values) values cannot be calculated.
This is a comprehensive [article](https://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/199912b.html#:%7E:text=An%20absolute%2Dsize%20keyword%20refers,need%20different%20scaling%20factors...).

Comment: The article is from 1999. Browsers behave nowadays differently. Do you have another source which is more up to date?